# Flutter and Firebase automatic sign-in after account creation

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I've already created a feature that allows me to create accounts using email and password with the built in firebase method `createUserWithEmailandPassword()`, but now i'm thinking of automatically signing in the user after account creation. I've searched a lot and hadn't come up with a solution to it, was wondering if anyone know if that is possible or if it isn't? Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the user is already signed in, then you can do the following:

```
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((res) {
      print(res);
      if (res != null) {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
        );
      }
      else
      {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignInPage()),
        );
      }
```

The `currentUser` will check if the user is already signed in and will automatically take the user to the `HomePage` screen.

Comment: Peter, Could you please show how to embed this code into the widget tree? Thanks.

Comment: check the splashscreen here https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-authentication-in-flutter-50e8b81cb29f, you can use the above code inside the initState

Comment: Peter, thank you. Is this also possible init `StatelessWidget`, i.e. without an `initState()` method?

Comment: Yes but if u want to update the state then use StatefulWidget

Comment: Thank you so much Peter, I didnt know the createUserWithEmailAndPassword() automatically signed in the user already. This works.

Answer (score 0):

create a userApi.dart

```
Future<FirebaseUser> getCurrentUser() async {
FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

if (user != null) {
  return user;
} else {
  return null;
}
}
```

and in main.dart

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Widget home;

APIs().usersAPI.getCurrentUser().then((u) {
  if (u == null) {
    print('USER IS NULL');
    setState(() {
   home = WelcomePage();
});
  } else {
    print('USER IS NOT NULL');
    setState(() {
   home = FeedPage();
});
  }
});

return MaterialApp(
  title: "Your Title",
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: FutureBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
     future: APIs().usersAPI.getCurrentUser(),
     builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot) {

        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.none:
            case ConnectionState.waiting: 
               return CircularProgressIndicator();
            default: 
               if (snapshot.hasError)
                  return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
               else
                 if(snapshot.data == null)
                    return WelcomePage();
                 else 
                    return FeedPage();
        }

     }
  ),
  routes: {
    '/login' : (context) => new LoginPage(),
    '/feed' : (context) => new FeedPage(),
  },
);
}
```